# А как определить кратность времени?

Tags: php

Имеем массив

```
$workingHours = [
        'понедельник' => ['08:00', '21:00'],
        'вторник' => ['20:00', '21:00'],
        'среда' => ['20:00', '21:00'],
        'четверг' => ['08:00', '09:00'],
        'пятница' => ['08:00', '21:00'],
        'суббота' => ['08:00', '21:00'],
        'воскресенье' => ['08:00', '21:00']
    ];
```

Как определить (точней выбрасывать исключение), что время должно быть кратно 15 минутам?
Есть что-то вроде? (для примера)

```
if (strtotime($value[$item][0]) % strtotime('15 minutes') !== 0 ) {
                echo strtotime('15 minutes');
                 throw new InvalidArgumentException('Время должно быть кратно 15 минутам. Неправильное время в '.$item);
            }
```

Comment: что должно получится?

Comment: Ну код, который я привел для примера, конечно, неудачный. Я хочу проверить время 08:15, 09:00 кратно ли оно 15 минутам. Чтобы, если пользователь вводит 08:17 - выпадало исключение

Comment: Проверять последние два символа на 00, 15, 30 и 45.

Comment: Вариант, да )) Не пришло в голову. Полез всякие diff() смотреть сначала

Comment: Если нужно действительно кратное периоду и без ограничений на только 00, 15, 30 и 45 то лучше вычислять количество минут в интервале и проверять, делится ли оно на 15 без остатка.